# How to transfer file using XMPP with openfire server in ios?

Tags: ios, xmpp

I need help to implement file transfer using openfire and xmpp.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement XMPP-0096. See documentation here http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0096.html